# ionic capacitor share plugin not sharing image with whatsapp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have created this function that shares image very well on many applications, but when it comes to **WhatsApp** or Instagram it not sharing the image.

#### I'm using Ionic v5 with capacitor v3

```js
  async shareImage() {
    let receiptName = 'Receipt N:123.png';
    const div = this.screenshotElement.nativeElement;
    const divHeight = div.clientHeight;
    const divWidth = div.clientWidth;
    const options = { background: '#ffffff', width: divWidth, height: divHeight };

    await Filesystem.requestPermissions();

    let base64Data = await domtoimage.toPng(div, options);

    // device shareing
    await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: receiptName,
      data: base64Data,
      directory: Directory.Cache
    });


    let fileResult = await Filesystem.getUri({
      directory: Directory.Cache,
      path: receiptName
    });

    let imageLink = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(fileResult.uri);

    Share.share({
      title: receiptName,
      text: receiptName,
      url: fileResult.uri,
    })
      .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing ::: ', error));

  }
```

import

```js
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import { Share } from '@capacitor/share';
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Camera, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/camera';
```

package

```
 "@capacitor/android": "^3.1.1",
        "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.2",
        "@capacitor/camera": "^1.0.3",
        "@capacitor/cli": "^3.1.1",
        "@capacitor/core": "^3.1.1",
        "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.0.2",
        "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.0.2",
        "@capacitor/ios": "^3.1.1",
        "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.0.2",
        "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.3",
        "@capacitor/share": "^1.0.3",
        "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.2",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that @capacitor/share has this known issue.

see: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/196

I solved it by using

```
npm install cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing
ionic cap sync
```

see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing

Comment: Does this open the same "native" share drawer as this plugin does?

Comment: Looks like still we cant share an Image along with a URL using capacitor fileshare. Did you see anything working recently without using cordova @mansour-alnasser?

Answer (score 1):

could also use [Capacitor Filesharer](https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-filesharer) saved me alot of stress!

Comment: Can you please share the code to share screenshot in capacitor 4 to share screenshots using the share button, thanks in advance